# Can a countable group have uncountably many distinct Hausdorff group topologies?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

**Question.** Can a countable group have an uncountable number of distinct Hausdorff group topologies?

By a group topology one understands a topology with respect to which the group operations are continuous.  By distinct I mean non-isomorphic as topological groups.

**Motivation.** The examples I have in mind are the pro-$p$ topologies on (e.g.) free groups, which typically yield an infinite (but countable) number of distinct topologies.  We can take the uncountably many subsets $\varpi$ of the primes and look at the pro-$\varpi$ topologies, but I'm not certain that they are all distinct.

Note that [a countable set can be topologised in uncountably many ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34838/are-there-uncountably-many-non-homeomorphic-ways-to-topologize-a-countably-infin).

(Interestingly, it seems that a kind of [dual question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499039/how-many-compatible-group-structures-does-a-topological-space-admit) has been asked before, which popped up in the list of similar questions.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, and the example you have in mind works. In more detail, the topologies on $\mathbb{Z}$ given by its diagonal inclusions into $\prod_{p \in S} \mathbb{Z}_p$ for all sets $S$ of primes are all distinct, and there are uncountably many of them. You can recover the set $S$ from the topology as follows: look at all of the sequences that converge to $0$. Given such a sequence, look at the set $S'$ of primes $p$ for which the $p$-adic norm of the sequence converges to $0$. Then $S$ is the intersection of all such $S'$.

Comment: Very slick. Thank you.